# How can I get the reference of the opened child window within the parent window?

Tags: javascript, html, web, client

I need to update the data on the child window from the parent window.

For this purpose I need to get the reference of the opened child window and pass the info to the child function named `UpdateInfo()`.

Here is the row that opens the child window in parent web page:

```
window.open("HTMLPage2.htm" , "child" , "width=200, height=100")
```

Any idea how can I get the reference of the opened child window within the parent window?

P.S. I don't know if my approach is right; is there a better approach?

Comment: `var myChild = window.open("HTMLPage2.htm" , "child" , "width=200, height=100")` => You can then reference the window by using `myChild`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open) returns a reference of the child window. You can use something like this:

```
var child = window.open("HTMLPage2.htm" , "child" , "width=200, height=100");
child.updateInfo(...);
```

This is possible only if the child's URL conforms to the [Same-Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

**EDIT**:
If the child *is not* from the same origin, you can still communicate with it via the [`window.postMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage) API. This enables you to send a message event to the child-window, and the child can listen to that event and invoke custom functionality.